# Pivot Not Appearing

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

Hi I have the following code that performs so manipulation on a sheets and creates a pivot table from this. My issue is that the pivot will not appear, the blank sheet "NoMilestonesPT" appears but it is blank with no table. I have purposefully left out column and row values, and it doesn't help if I add them.

Can anyone see what may be wrong?

Thanks

```
    Sub projectsWithoutMilestone()




    'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("NoMilestones").Delete
    Worksheets("SOWMilestoneList").Delete
    Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "NoMilestones"
    Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "SOWMilestoneList"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Switch off error masking
    On Error GoTo 0

     Sheets("DemandTable").Select
    Range("Table_Demand458910[#All]").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("NoMilestones").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Unlist


    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim pasteRowIndex As Long



    With Sheets("NoMilestones")


     Dim SOW As String

 Dim SowRow As Long

 SowRow = 1

    .Columns(3).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    .Columns(4).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    .Cells(1, "C").Value = "SOW contains Milestones"
    .Cells(1, "D").Value = "Record has Milestone"


 Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    LastRow = Worksheets("NoMilestones").UsedRange.Rows.Count



    For r = 1 To LastRow


        If LCase(.Cells(r, "N").Value) Like LCase("Milestone*") Then
       .Cells(r, "D").Value = "Has Milestones"


       SOW = .Cells(r, "B").Value
       ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SOWMilestoneList").Cells(SowRow, "A").Value = SOW
       ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SOWMilestoneList").Cells(SowRow, "B").Value = "True"

       SowRow = SowRow + 1




   End If

       Next r

       Range("C2").Select

        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],SOWMilestoneList!C[-2]:C[-1],2,FALSE)"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C18990")
    Range("C2:C18990").Select

      Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False



    End With


    Dim PSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PCache As PivotCache
    Dim PTable As PivotTable
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim LastRow1 As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long


    'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("NoMilestonesPT").Delete
    Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "NoMilestonesPT"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set PSheet = Worksheets("NoMilestonesPT")
    Set DSheet = Worksheets("NoMilestones")
    On Error Resume Next

    'Define Data Range
    LastRow1 = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow1, LastCol)


'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="NoMilestonesPivotTable")


    'Insert Blank Pivot Table
    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="NoMilestonesPivotTable")



End Sub
```

Comment: You need another `On Error Goto 0` after the second `On Error Resume Next` which is currently hiding your real problem.

Comment: @Rory thanks I have added that, seems to throw an error where it is defining the Pivot Cache, notably the line `TableName:="NoMilestonesPivotTable")`

Comment: Why do you have two lines creating pivot tables?

Comment: @Rory I didn't think I did, one creates the cache for the pivot table, the other creates the blank pivot table. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Nope - note the 2 CreatePivottable statements

Comment: Why is that error masking even there? Ditch it if you don't have a specific reason. Otherwise you end up with cases exactly like this where your code doesn't work but you have no idea why.

Comment: @jeffreyweir It is there because if no sheet yet exists that it needs to delete and create new, it will cause an error.